# Why is there such intense questioning of passengers on flights to US and Canada?

Tags: air-travel

When flying to the US and Canada, the airline usually interviews you very intensely - triple checking your visa and asking you about your plans. The questioning is at times more detailed than what US/Canadian immigration actually asks when you reach your destination. In comparison, flights from North America to Schengen countries are extremely lax - nobody ever asks you any questions or even bothers to verify if you've exceeded the 90/180 rule.

What's the reason behind this? Surely Schengen countries fine carriers for carrying passengers without a proper visa just like their North American counterparts, so why don't airlines check those flights just as strictly?

> NB: The above only applies to non-US/Canadian citizens

Comment: This is not always the case. My wife and I (both US passport holders) have flown multiple times Oslo > Oakland and Gatwick > Oakland in the last few years, and we've never been interviewed before flying, just asked to show our passports.

Comment: @David it would not be surprising at all if the behavior described in this question were encountered only by people other than US passport holders.

Comment: I've found the reverse - not usually much scrutiny on checking in, much more questioning on arrival in US (although it seems to be incredibly variable). Then again I haven't been to the US recently...

Comment: Is there evidence that this is widespread among the majority of airlines, and the majority of passengers (or some specific subset)?  Or are you  extrapolating from your personal experience?

Comment: @phoog Of course, that's perfectly reasonable and I agree. But the original question wasn't limited to certain passport holders, and presumed (if only by inference) that what the poster experiences happens to everyone.

Comment: 'Surely Schengen countries fine carriers just like America'. Have you researched this? Remembering that the US is in the middle of a massive wave of paranoia about illegal immigration.

Comment: On nonstop flights from India to the United States, passengers are required to pass through an extra security check at the gate. Is this related?

Comment: @gparayani that's related too.

Comment: I have experienced extra-stringent screening when flying from Brussels to Washington, which is attributed to the EU and NATO traffic (BRU being the closest airport with TATL service from Antwerp), and was even strip searched in 2002. But I've not had any extra scrutiny departing for IAD from LHR, AMS, FRA, or MUC vs, say, NRT or PTY. Once you arrive, though, Customs does seem to be extra picky about bags from Amsterdam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From experience, this depends *a lot* on the airport (and maybe the shift you meet too). You might just have been flying from an airport that is 'sharper'.

I fly many times a year from different German airports to the US, and it is always easy-peasy, except MUC (Munich) - there it takes much longer, long questioning, full camera disassembly required, all electronics out and rescanned, etc. Either from bad experience or different training, MUC personnel has a very different approach.